# Is catching a global exception a good way to handle reconnecting?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a growing application with multiple usercontrols, windows, etc that all send a lot of data across a socket that's established when the program is opened (signing into a server). If the server ever dies or something along those lines, I'd like to be able to handle the ensuing SocketException in a more graceful way than wrapping pretty much every code block in try-catch statements for that specific exception.

```
void App_DispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
```

Using that should catch any unhandled exception that gets thrown, would it be a bad idea to simply check if the exception is a socketexception and then launch the "you have disconnected, please reconnect" code? With this application, you can safely assume that 99% of any socketexception thrown would be because of a server disconnect.

And while I'm on the subject, any idea how you check the exception type after it's already caught? With the above code, I can get the original exception simply with e.Exception. I'm not really sure how to word an if statement to check the type of an exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMHO this is a very bad idea...

A better solution would be to move the code accessing the socket into its own class... anything in the application needing to interact with the server goes through that class... this way any socket-related exception can be handled accordingly in a central location.

Comment: I considered this originally, but the problem is, what if the disconnect occurs in the middle of a block of code making several socket uses? If the exception is handled by its own class, the exception is caught there, and now this thread is in the middle of an operation, while a new connection has been established and the server isn't handling any operation. This can lead to so many problems, so I want an exception thrown on that thread too to stop it.

Comment: And having the socket wrapper throw a new exception to do that brings me back to the original issue I'm trying to avoid, having a ton of try-catch statements around every block of code to handle this. All I want is "If there is a SocketException, kill the method that was currently running and launch the reconnect code"

Comment: @cost I understand that but this just means that you need to design the interface of the class accordingly... for example it can have some sort of "transactional behaviour" which would solve the described scenario in an elegant manner IMO...

Comment: @cost there is no magic bullet to achieve that - the global handler wouldn't give you this either... if there is "state" involved then you will end up with either a "transactional wrapper class" and/or some try-/catch-blocks...

Comment: It is a large application with literally thousands of unique socket operations. Designing an interface that complex would be more work than all those try-catch blocks I mentioned. It would be unmanageable to try to stick all of that code into a socket wrapping class. You never said why you thought it was a bad idea to use the global exception.

Comment: Why wouldn't the global handler give this to me? Wouldn't it allow the exception to bubble up and stop the thread I want to stop?

Comment: @cost a global exception handler is for handling situation you can't foresee... your case is different - you know exactly where you need to handle it... another point: a global exception handler doesn't know any context/state information which is needed in all (but the simplest) cases to handle such a situation gracefully... another point: if the application needs to scale up (for example more than one connection) this is going to need rather big redesign etc.

Comment: @cost another point: if there are "native resources" (which is very likely when dealing with sockets) they might end up "not being disposed of" which will lead to more problems later on...

Comment: @cost your design sounds like it has some flaws which lead to this situation... adding a global exception handler to that is the sort of "quick fix" which comes back to bite you in my experience there are always some side-effects with such "global quick fixes"...

Comment: One thing I am certain of is there will never be more than one connection at a time. The whole design of the program revolves around that. I fail to see where there would be a flaw in this case; lots of things are using the socket, I want, in every instance of SocketException thrown, to call the same block of reconnect code. How is this, functionally, any difference from catching all of those exceptions differently?

Comment: You make a lot of points that don't apply to this case. It doesn't need to know about the context, as I say in the question. There will never be more than one connection on the grand scale, all other small connections to a different socked have their SocketExceptions handled there. I can't think of any native resources that wouldn't get freed in this case since the socket is recycled anyway as part of the reconnect code

Comment: @cost the "scale up" aspect was just one example... I can only strongly recommend avoiding to use global exception handler for this... IMO opinion the flaw is already in the architecture (not enough abstraction, no exception handling etc.). If you read the other points I wrote you will see that there are lots of differences between handling this "locally and/or encapsulated" versus "globally". IF you really want to go the "global" way I can only wish you luck...

Comment: @cost there might always be sort of 1 in a million special case where handling it globally might be possibly right... since I don't know your case I can only give you answers which apply to similar cases in general and won't be wrong even in the one "special case"...

Comment: There's already a lot of abstraction and exception handling. In the end it still comes down to I have to kill whatever thread was using the socket when it broke, and no amount of worthwhile abstraction can make that go away.

Comment: @cost you know your specific case best - good luck with handling this globally...

Comment: I appreciate your advice, but none of your suggestions would allow me to do what is essential here. Encapsulating this in the socket wrapper would still be, in the end, having each of those blocks of code wrapped try-catch statements. Unless I wanted to do something really ugly like putting every socket request in a huge switch statement and just wrapping that whole big thing. But that would be terrible to manage

Comment: @cost please read the link from Eric Lippert posted by Sandeep (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

```
Using that should catch any unhandled exception that gets thrown
```

Catching all the exceptions, where you can do little is not a good idea.

[Eric Lippert has a very good article on what exception is handled.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions.aspx)

I agree with Yahia that code accessing Socket moved to its own class.

```
public class SocketHandling
{

 //if Something goes wrong, throw exception. It is up to the caller how to handle the exception.
}

main()
{
  try
{

}

catch(SocketRelatedException)
{
  //handle the exception.
}
}
```

Comment: I'd like to emphasize that every 10th line of code involves a socket operation. Nearly every method

Comment: That is a good article and I'm dealing with a lot of exogenous exceptions here, but the code you added doesn't help me any. "if Something goes wrong, throw exception. It is up to the caller how to handle the exception." That's the point of this question. I already have an exception thrown if something goes wrong, SocketException. The caller has to handle an exception in both cases, so I'm back to square one of trying to avoid a ton of try-catch statements

Comment: I am sorry. I did not understand what do you meant by both cases.

Comment: I have a lot of code that doesn't need exception handling, aside from what would be generated by a SocketException. The point of me wanting to use a global exception handling is to catch them all in the same place, was to avoid having a ton of try{ every method } catch (SocketException e) {Reconnect()} statements. When I say both cases, I mean that having an exception thrown by my socket wrapper and having the caller handle it doesn't give me a difference problem to solve

Comment: I would just have to wrap all of those callers then. All I want to do is, when SocketException is thrown by anything, to completely get out of the thread that was running it. Kill whatever method was in the middle of using it.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it is bad practice to check the exception type.

```
catch(Exception ex) 
            {
            if (ex is System.Net.Sockets.SocketException)
                {
                    doSomething(ex);
                }
            else 
              throw;

            }
```

Also, you can just catch a specific exception type...